# RegEx for extracting chars between colons

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to extract text between two colons, without them and spaces, but with my code I am getting two colons always.

Sentence is: `xxxxxxx: hello world, my name is AAAA :description`

Now, I would need: `hello world, my name is AAAA`

With `(\:[^:]*\:)` I am getting:  `: hello world, my name is AAAA :`

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Put them outside of the capturing group `:([^:]*):` or use `:\K[^:]+(?=:)`

Comment: ```:([^:]*):``` still the same, returns text with colons

Comment: That is the full match but you have to get the first capturing group. Did you try the second option?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but the second one returns "no results"

Comment: Can you add the code you are trying to the question?

Comment: There is no code, I am just trying to create Calculated Field in Tableau to extract text . Nothing else.

Comment: Does `(?<=:)[^:]*(?=:)` work?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, don't know how to give you some reputations but I would like to say "Thanks" here. Cheers!

Comment: You are welcome. I have added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert what is on the left and what is on the right is a colon.

For the matching you could use a negated character class `[^:]*` to match to match 0+ times not a colon. If you want to match at least 1 character you could change the quantifier to `+` instead of `*`

```
(?<=:)[^:]*(?=:)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/viFCus/1)